# handle the submission form from mutiple domains to remote server

Tags: php, cross-domain

I've been asked to develop a php rest api that sends emails and the api will be hosted on a remote server. They have multiple sites ( landing pages ) with simple html + JS and these sites for some reason we can't include any server side script. We want to add the url in the action of the form something like that

```
<form action= "http://remotesite/api/submit.php" method="post" >
```

I was planing to restrict the api to receive request from specific domains ( our clients ) using something like this

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.info")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

but I've read that request origin information can be modified. Is there a secure solution for what I want to do without using server side language in the form page ?

-- I am thinking of using `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to get the source ip and match on the remote side with a white list of ip(s). Would that be a secure solution ?

Comment: You could send the form data to your local server and then send the data from your local server to the remote server with cURL. This way, the remote server will not be exposed to your application users and you can add additional security measures in the backend (like adding a token that you can validate on the remote site or something similar).

Comment: @jeromegamez that's actually a complete answer, not a comment! right that up as an answer as it does solve the OP's question. this also allows specific IP's whitelisted in remote server

Answer (score 0):

You could send the form data to your local server and then send the data from your local server to the remote server with cURL.

This way, the remote server will not be exposed to your application users and you can add additional security measures in the backend (like adding a token that you can validate on the remote site or something similar).

As said by @Patrick, this would also allow you to whitelist the local server's IP in the remote server's code.

Comment: It's a good idea but I've been informed that the local server doesn't support php, that's why I can't use php on the form side.